# How to share text from Android Chrome with other apps?

Tags: google-chrome, android-intent, share-intent

I want a button in a webpage in Android Chrome that shows the "Share with" dialog so that a text is sent, for example, to the email app.

I have this:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=text/plain;end">Share</a>
```

..but it is not working, Chrome says "Navigation is blocked". Any idea?